# Android background service

Tags: android, background-service

I'm developing an Android application that has a list of items. What options do I have to make a background service to update that list from a webservice from time to time, asking first for the user permission?
Can you provide code samples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the option to make a background service to update that list from a webservice from time to time, asking first for the user permission

Answer (score 2):

- Implement a user interface where you will have settings for update interval
- implement an alarm, so that is fired as the user set it
- make your alarm start your service, your service starts a thread, and updates the content, saves to database

you can search the stackoverflow site for example how to use alarms, broadcasts, services and threads